# Ubuntu completely remove python that is not Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have just spent 2 days trying to build Tensorflow from source, and finally succeeded when I realized that `sudo pip` (even with the -H flag) was not finding my anaconda pip, but instead finding a pip installed with apt.  Running, then, `sudo -H ~/anaconda3/bin/pip ...` fixed my problem.

In order to avoid this kind of issue ever again (I had several issues in this process with the "wrong" python being used), is it possible for me to completely remove python from my system, keeping only Anaconda?  Is it advisable?

Comment: Do not do this. If you want to know 'which' python will be used, try running `which python` on the command line.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, Python is used by a lot of different system packages; uninstalling it means breaking the OS. In general, install system-level packages with `apt` and anything else using Anaconda's virtual environment. If you source the virtual environment, the `pip` binary used is always the one in the environment.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick efforts to prevent me from breaking my system!  Fortunately, everything's snapshotted because I like to Ubuntu in VMs :-).  Bit of a clarification though - if my anaconda installation is accessible via the path etc..., would a purge of the non-anaconda python still break stuff?

Comment: One observation - it appears that using the `virtualenv` approach prevents a user from building Tensorflow from source, so it can't take full advantage of the machine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. Python is an essential part of ubuntu (and of just any linux distrib nowadays), so removing it will just break your system. Well, if you want a broken system then it's of course up to you ;)

The right solution is to [use virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for your own workspaces instead, so you can have different isolated installs with different python and 3rd part packages versions. This also avoids breaking anything when two projects depends on different versions of a same package. For a local use you probably want to install [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) too (it's an addon over virtualenv that makes working with virtualenvs easier - switching between virtualenvs, running hooks on env switch etc).

Oh and yes: those virtualenvs are per-user so no more sudo and you don't risk messing up your system install (thx Attie for mentioning this).

And to be even more exhaustive: darthbith mentions in a comment that anaconda has [it's own virtualization/package management system conda](http://stuarteberg.github.io/conda-docs/) that [might make virtualenv redundant](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/#Myth-#5:-conda-doesn't-work-with-virtualenv,-so-it's-useless-for-my-workflow) and is anyway a best fit if you're using anaconda.

Comment: I'd also mention that when using a virtualenv, one should typically not use `sudo`, as this can risk confusion-with and corruption-of the underlying system.

Comment: +1 good answer. One small thing: please do not use virtualenvs with Conda, use conda environments instead. They do not play nicely together. I only mention this since the question is tagged (and talks about) Anaconda/conda

Comment: @darthbith thanks for the tip, added the info to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not just a Ubuntu issue but also a linux world wide issue. The system python is at the core of apt-get and yum package managers. Also the modern grub is based on python so removing it can make your machine unbootable.

In short, this will affect RHEL related distributions (CentOS/Fedora) and Debian related distributions (Debian/Ubuntu).